# What's the meaning of this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function fmoney(s, n) {
        //debugger;
        n = n > 0 && n <= 20 ? n : 0;
        s = parseFloat((s + "").replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, "")).toFixed(n) + "";
        var l = s.split(".")[0].split("").reverse(),
            r = s.split(".")[1] || "",
            t = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            t += l[i] + ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && (i + 1) != l.length ? "," : "");
        }
        if (r) {
            r = "." + r;
        };
        return t.split("").reverse().join("") + r;
    }
```

I can't know the meaning of "/[^\d.-]/"，can you tell me ? Thank you very much

Comment: `replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, "")` this removes all non-digit, non-period and non-minus symbols from string

Comment: There is a portal called [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VGHEa9/1) which explains every component of your regex along with ability to test it.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much